# Cannot decrypt message encrypted with private key using the public key -RSA

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, rsa

Just doing some tests to try to get a better understanding of how this works.  I thought any message encrypted with the private key could be decrypted with the public key.  Am I misunderstanding this or is there something wrong with my code?  I know it works fine the other way. (encoded with public, decoded with private) Here is my test code.

```
            /*
             * PKCS 1
             * keys created with ssh-keygen -m PEM
             * PKCS1 public key created with ssh-keygen -f <priv key> -e -m pem
             */            
            string privPKCS1Key = File.ReadAllText(@"keys/pkcs1_unencrypted.pem");
            string publicPKCS1Key = File.ReadAllText(@"keys/pkcs1_unencrypted.pub");

            //load private PKCS 1 key
            var privPKCS1RSA = RSA.Create();
            string encString = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                privPKCS1RSA.ImportFromPem(privPKCS1Key);

                var enc = privPKCS1RSA.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Message"), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                encString = Convert.ToBase64String(enc);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message has been encoded by PKCS1 private key [{encString}]");
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

            //load public PKCS1 key                        
            var pubPKCS1RSA = RSA.Create();
            try
            {                
                pubPKCS1RSA.ImportFromPem(publicPKCS1Key);

                var pubPKCS1Decrypt = pubPKCS1RSA.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encString), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                string pkcs1DecryptString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pubPKCS1Decrypt);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message has been decoded with the PKCS1 public key [{pkcs1DecryptString}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

            /*
             * Reverse this... encode with public and decode with private..works fine
             */
            string pubEncString = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var pubEnc = pubPKCS1RSA.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Encrypted with PKCS1 public"), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                pubEncString = Convert.ToBase64String(pubEnc);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message has been encoded with PKCS1 public key [{pubEncString}]");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

            try
            {
                var privDec = privPKCS1RSA.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(pubEncString), RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
                string privDecString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(privDec);
                Console.WriteLine($"Message has been decoded with PKCS1 private key [{privDecString}]");
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

I appreciate assistance in pointing out my error or clarifying my understanding. I have seen messages about digital signatures and I will look into that as well. But this was just a simple test to learn with.

Comment: No.  You need both  private and public key.  Private key is a constant that gets loaded on both encrypted and decrypted software.  Each message has unique public key that is used once and really a random number.  Receive end uses both the private key and public key to decrypt message.

Comment: You misunderstood. It's the other way round: A message encrypted with the public key can be decrypted with the private key.

Comment: What is the point of an encryption that can be decrypted with the public key that anyone can have? Maybe you mean signing (with the private key) and verifying (with the public key). For this purpose .NET has dedicated classes.

Comment: Almost certainly you are actually encrypting with the public key. The RSA private keys that the RSA class generates and/or imports contain the public key components as well. So `RSA.Encrypt()` is actually a public key operation. If your RSA object was created from a private key the private key parts are simply ignored for operations that only make sense for public key, like RSA encryption.

Comment: @Xaver - I already said that direction worked without issue.  Lots of RSA tutorials claim you can decrypt both ways.  I wanted to test that theory.

Comment: @Topaco - One method I read was to encrypt with your private key and then with their public key so you can be sure it came from you and was meant for them.  I might be confusing that with signing.  Which I full intention of exploring further.

Comment: S. [digital signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature), C# has dedicated methods for this, e.g. [`SignData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.signdata?view=net-6.0) and [`VerifyData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.verifydata?view=net-6.0). Sometimes signing is referred to as encryption with the private key, which is misleading and, strictly speaking, generally even wrong.

Comment: @Topaco - Thank you, that is probably what is throwing me off so much.  Will dig into that today.

Comment: @Topaco - so here is what I have now.  Let me know if I have this correct.
1)Encrypt with their public key
2)Sign it with local private key
3)Send both
4) Remote Side verifies signature
5)Remote Side Decrypts data if signature is valid.

Comment: Encryption and signatures are independent of each other and are not necessarily used in combination (as in the scenario you describe, if I understand it correctly). They can be used together, but the naive combination of both has vulnerabilities, see e.g. this post about [public key authenticated encryption](https://neilmadden.blog/2018/11/26/public-key-authenticated-encryption-and-why-you-want-it-part-ii/) for more details.

Comment: Some useful links [on RSA encryption with a private key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-with-a-private-key-the-same-as-signature-generation) and on [signing together with encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5458/1172).

Comment: Excellent articles, Thanks @Topaco and Maarten.  In the one article it mentions bonding the public key to the signature.  How do you do that in code?  I can't seem to find any examples of it.

Comment: I don't know an example, however signatures, keys, etc. are ultimately byte sequences and byte sequences can be concatenated. Separation is possible on basis of the lengths. The signature size is known (just like the ciphertext size), since in RSA it's equal to the key size. Alternatively, the size can be stored in the byte sequence.